# Есть ли разница между free() и g_free()

Tags: c, gtk, free

Собственно, есть ли разница между этими функциями?

Допустим, мы получаем строку:

```
const gchar *const str = g_convert(...);
```

И делаем:

```
free(str);
```

Может ли одна функция заменить другую, или это **UB**?

Ну и, собственно, может ли **char** заменять **gchar**, **int** - **gint** и так далее?

Comment: Для себя наверно стоит прочитать про системные вызовы `brk`, `sbrk` и понять что в любых алокаторах в конечном счёте используются именно они. В реализации `alloca` их не используют, вроде :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никто не знает и не должен знать, есть ли между ними разница. Если вы выделяли память через `g_malloc`, то и освобождать ее надо функцией `g_free`. А уж что там у них спрятано внутри - не оговаривается.

В [документации](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html) ясно сказано

> It's important to match `g_malloc()` (and wrappers such as `g_new()`) with `g_free()`, `g_slice_alloc()` (and wrappers such as `g_slice_new()`) with `g_slice_free()`, plain `malloc()` with `free()`, and (if you're using C++) `new` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete[]`. Otherwise bad things can happen, since these allocators may use different memory pools (and `new`/`delete` call constructors and destructors).

Результат `g_convert`, как сказано в документации к этой функции, должен освобождаться именно через `g_free()`.

Comment: Понял, благодарю.

Comment: Вроде там магик ид в начале втыкают, размером с `int` , это про внутренности.. хотя если интересно лучше глянуть самому исходники.

Comment: @NewView, не... это [обычная обёртка](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/gmem.c#L191) над `free()` без чего-либо интересного...